# Will one fulfill his obligation of hearing the shofar on Rosh Hashanah if it is done via livestream due to Covid reasons?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year, shofar, covid19-pandemic

It is an echoing sound so not sure if Rosh Hashanah 3:7 agrees or disagrees.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya!

Answer (score -2):

During "normal circumstances", e.g. non-Covid situations, it seems to be not allowed to hear the Shofar over an internet connection. See for example what the Lubavitcher Rebbe says (Torat Menachem, 5744, vol. 3, Parshat Balak, p. 2124. See: [Shofar Over the Internet During Elul?](https://www.chabad.org/holidays/JewishNewYear/template_cdo/aid/4853572/jewish/Shofar-Over-the-Internet-During-Elul.htm)). The Rebbe writes:

> Regarding hearing the Torah or the Megillah et al., one does not fulfill their obligation by hearing it through a tape or other device . . . even with respect to the custom of hearing the shofar during the month of Elul, which is done merely to arouse the person to do teshuvah, as the verse states, “Will a shofar be sounded in the city and the people not tremble?” one should not hear it through a recording, since it needs to arouse one’s feelings to teshuvah and it needs to be done similar to “words that come from the heart enter the heart,” which does not apply to hearing through these devices.

Similary, the Gemara [(Rosh Hashanah 27b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Rosh_Hashanah.27b.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) explains:

> if he clearly heard the sound of the shofar, he has fulfilled his obligation; but if he heard the sound of an echo, he has not fulfilled his obligation.

[The Shulchan Aruch HaRav (Alter Rebbe) (587:1)](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/3376118/jewish/Shulchan-Aruch-Chapter-587-Laws-Relating-to-One-who-Sounds-the-Shofar-in-a-Cistern.htm) states also that it is not permitted:

> The sound of the shofar must be heard without the admixture of any other sound at all. If one heard the sound [of the shofar] together with another sound, he has not fulfilled his obligation

So, according to these sources, the sound of the Shofar needs to be heard by the person in a clear way, thus directly. If you listen to the Shofar via Teams or Zoom, there can be some noise and that makes the sound of the Shofar not clear.

But what to do during Covid-19?

On viewing a Livestream on Shabbos, [the Halakhic Guidance from CJLS about Coronavirus](https://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/story/halakhic-guidance-cjls-about-coronavirus) says the following:

> Our committee has not made a formal ruling on livestreaming on Shabbat and Yom Tov (a copy of the draft proposal is available to RA members by request), but for the current sha’at hadehak, (pressing circumstances) those congregations that are already offering streaming and that are still able to hold services with a minyan, should encourage members whose health may be at risk, or whose presence may be a risk to others, to stay home and make use of this option if the alternative would be to risk their own health or the health of others by attending services. Every attempt should be made to reduce potential violations of shabbat (for example, activating the stream before Shabbat or holiday, or having the stream activated in an unusual way, or by someone who is not of the Jewish faith).

On hearing the Megillah or the Shofar, [they write](https://www.rabbinicalassembly.org/story/halakhic-guidance-cjls-about-coronavirus#:%7E:text=Some%20poskim%20have,not%20a%20recording.%C2%A0%C2%A0):

> Some poskim have expressed concern about whether one fulfills one’s obligation to hear Megillah reading by doing so via amplification or electronic reproduction, declaring it to be similar to shofar, where the mitzvah is to “hear” the shofar, so the actual sound must be heard.  In fact, the Mitzvah of megillah is described in terms of its reading: “mikra megillah.” hearing it is just another form of reading it. Hearing the Megillah being read via telephone or live streaming, is permitted when necessary, so long as the sound is undistorted, live and not a recording.

A source I highly recommend reading is [פסקי קורונה](https://collectingthesetimes.org/s/collecting-these-times/item/6428) (Piskei Corona) by Rav Hershel Schachter, a responsa specially made for Covid-19.

---

So, concluding: "Hearing the Megillah being read via telephone or live streaming, is permitted when necessary, so long as the sound is undistorted, live and not a recording."- it seems that this also applies to hearing the Shofar, only if the sound is undistorted, live and not a recording (not from 1 hour ago for example).

Comment: May I assume that the sound of the shofar that I hear on the street is live, even though it may have electronic origins of which I am unaware?

Comment: @PhilFreedenberg It seems true according to the Halakhic Guidance from CJLS. The only prerequisite is that it is live broadcasted and there is no delay in the broadcast.

Comment: I think they are drawing a distinction between megillah, where hearing a livestream is a form of reading the megillah, and shofar, where one needs to here the sound of shofar, but electronic output from a device.

Comment: CJLS is Conservative, and thus would not be relied on by most users of this site. Orthodox rabbis did not allow using the internet for Corona over Rosh Hashana.

Comment: @N.T. I did not know that, Thanks!

Comment: @N.T. Practically that's true, but there's still room for interesting lomdus if you'd be yotzei or not.  There's probably a way to make it "only" derabanan, which means that theoretically someone could have done it before that derabanan was enacted (even if in practice there was never a time when the technology existed and the derabanan didn't).

Comment: @Heshy That lomdus was discussed in many other areas: hearing Megillah, krias hatorah, siyum on erev Pesach, etc.